# Send multi-touch events to Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, multi-touch

I need to test an Android application that takes multi-touch input, such as pinch and rotate.  I'd like to test this using the emulator if possible.  Is there a way to send Linux input events, via ADB or otherwise, without modifying the Android source?

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/touch-devices.html

Events such as ABS_MT_POSITION_X, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y, and ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but still open.
Indeed there are options:

1.) Send commands via telnet (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console)

2.) Use adb like (input tap X Y), e.g.

```
adb shell input tap 100 100
```